# Oracle Update Where Target Has Duplicates

Tags: oracle

Suppose I have the following tables

Target table

```
   sales
   ID      ItemNum     DiscAmt    OrigAmt
   1       123         20.00      NULL
   2       456         30.00      NULL
   3       123         20.00      NULL
```

Source Table

```
   prices 
   ItemNum      OrigAmt
   123          25.00
   456          35.00
```

I tried to update the OrigAmt in the Target Table using the OrigAmt in the Source Table using

```
  UPDATE
  (   SELECT    s.OrigAmt dests
          ,p.OrigAmt srcs            
      FROM      sales s
      LEFT JOIN prices p
      ON        s.ItemNum = p.ItemNum
   ) amnts
   SET amnts.dests = amnts.srcs
   ;
```

but i get: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
i also tried using the merge but i get: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Is your source table unique on `ItemNum`?

Comment: yes it is unique, sorry to miss that out

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generally UPDATE the result of an arbitrary SELECT.

Single statement, assuming ItemNum is a primary key for prices:

```
 UPDATE sales WHERE (SELECT count(price.ItemNum) FROM price 
     WHERE price.ItemNum = sales.ItemNum) > 0
 SET OrigAmt = 
     (SELECT MAX(OrigAmt) FROM price 
     WHERE price.ItemNum = sales.ItemNum)
```

You might get away with omitting the WHERE and/or MAX.

Less convoluted: loop a cursor over

```
 SELECT ItemNum, OrigAmt FROM price
```

performing a number of updates for each ItemNum from table prices:

```
 UPDATE sales SET OrigAmt=? WHERE ItemNum=?
```